# Virtual Audio Cable and skype

Tags: windows, audio, skype, cable

I need a way to send computer sound AND microphone sound through Skype. I have had  a set up in the past that involved using Virtual Audio Cable and like 3 or 4 instances of its repeaters, but I have scoured the internet for the past few hours and cannot find what I am looking for.... This post from someone here on these forums is *close* to the set up... but of course they didnt bother to include any real order for what they were talking about:

"use VAC 10 to create 3 virtual cables, then setup audio out on Skype to line 1 and mic to line 2. now use audiorepeater.exe from VAC 10 and open 4 of those. set one box to line 1 and then your speakers, another box to line 2 and your microphone jack, the third box to line 3 to your speakers, and the fourth box from line 3 to line 2. finally go to your playback devices on windows and set line 3 as your default output."

I had assumed that this is either in order of [input -> output] OR [output -> input] but it's not. It seems this user just posted random orders for each repeater so of course I cant figure it out without tiresome trial and error.... Can anyone clarify the correct order?

Comment: I should clarify too, I dont want the person in the skype call to hear their-own voice echoed back at them... just the game sound / my mic sound.

Answer (score 0):

To Send Music and your Mic on Skype, the best solution is Voicemeeter (www.voicemeeter.com). follow user manual up to use case #1: http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf